# simultaneously reading 100 telnet connections c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I want to write a progam in c++ which creates 100+ connections
to telnet server and read their datastreams (parse and interpret them).
Should i use one thread for every connection? Or is there another
method to handle so many connections without hundreds of threads?

Comment: Try single-threaded I/O multiplexing with non-blocking I/O first. You can probably even go orders of magnitude higher than your stated goal with that approach.

Comment: To build on @KerrekSB's suggestion: look at the `select()` and `poll()` functions man page. There might be a C++ wrapper in some kind of package, but the C versions are what has worked well for 3 generations of this kind of application.

Comment: You might want to look at [libevent](libevent.org) or Boost.Asio to simplify the networking side. I would probably attack this by having one thread reading the network IO and feeding the results to a small pool of std::thread workers.

Comment: `select()` can by default wait on 64 sockets. 64 is the value of `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` for `WaitForMultipleObjects` that is called inside `select`. For more than 64 sockets you need to make groups of 64 (or rather 63) and handle them in more than one thread.

Comment: @Dialecticus: IIRC it was a matter of setting a macro to increase that limit. Is it this `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the simplest form, you can use one thread per connection. But that won't scale to much more than your hundreds of connections, and the multithreading may make your code and logic more complex (it very well may make it simpler too. It depends very much on what your application is trying to do.)

A little better than that is to use `select`. It's a function call that most (all?) socket libraries and operating systems support. Basically, you put all your sockets in a set and you give the set to `select` and tell it to wait for any event on any of these sockets (an event is something like new data arriving on a socket or a connection error or a write completing or stuff like that.) If any events occur on any of these sockets, the `select` call will return and tell you what has happened on which socket(s). Then you process those events (read the incoming data, write more data, handle the errors, etc.) and then loop back and wait for more events.

There are many good tutorials around about `select` and event-driven programming in general. Also, there are more efficient (albeit platform-specific) system calls and facilities, e.g. `poll`, `epoll`, `kqueue`, `inotify`, etc.

There are of course many excellent libraries that use the most efficient platform-specific method and give you a (mostly) simple interface to work with. Libraries such as [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [libevent](http://libevent.org/) and [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv).

If you don't need Windows portability, I suggest *libev*. *libevent* is a little older and larger, but with many more features. If you do need to support Windows, use *libuv*.

But handling the connections and their events is just part of the solution. As mentioned by comments on your question and other answer(s), after you receive an event on a connection, one common (not to mention sensible and scalable) solution is to hand off the actual processing of data and activities like that to other threads.

What is usually done is having a *pool* of worker threads. In your main thread, you get notified of an even on a connection (by `select`, etc.) but instead of doing all the work in the main thread, you give the work item to one of the worker threads to process and generate the result for and send the result back.

One crucial issue here will be the communication between the main thread (the `select` thread) and the worker threads. Sometimes, some form of thread-safe shared queue is used. The main thread puts works items (events, requests, whatever) in this queue, and all the worker threads try to grab an item from this queue whenever they are not busy.

Note that everything you read above is simplified to the bare minimum. In the real world, writing low-latency and scalable systems of this kind is a challenging and complicated task, so you might want to do (a lot) more research if you really need performance and/or you are dealing with huge amounts of data and many clients.

Comment: 'the multithreading will make your code and logic more complex' - what? If you use one thread per telnet connection, the code for multiple connections is the same as for one connection - no explicit state machine required.  If you are going to recommend select etc, use valid arguments.

Comment: @MartinJames: We can argue this all day long, but I was thinking in terms of internal application state and data that has to be shared among those threads. Handling the state of each connection may (and does) become easier, but usually that's not all the application does. It has to provide some services to those at the other ends of those connections, and these services will likely use shared data and resources. Anyways, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Second half of the answer shamelessly picked up from http://stackoverflow.com/a/17605184/383045 , i.e. the other answer on this question from Nikos C.

Answer (score 3):

yzt's answer is already good, but here's another, "hybrid" approach.

Instead of using a separate thread for each connection, only use a thread from a thread pool for actually handling traffic. In your central loop, where you poll select(), you dispatch work to the next free thread. If there are no more threads available, you either simply wait for one to become available, or spawn more threads to handle the additional traffic.

This provides better latencies because the next socket doesn't have to wait unless the thread pool is exhausted and you don't want to spawn more threads.

Comment: Well pointed-out! I hope you don't mind that I shamelessly incorporated your answer into mine!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is tagged as `boost-asio` so.. You can use it to handle way more than 100 connections and way more than 10000 connections too (depending on your program CPU and memory usage). Check out [boost examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) to study how to do this. I think your telnet case can be strarted from [example tcp echo server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)